# Is there a way to force an Xcode bot to do a clean checkout?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I erroneously thought selecting "Cleaning: Always" in the "Schedule" tab of an Xcode bot configuration would force the bot to `rm -rf` its checkouts directory at the start of every integration, but this does not appear to be the case.

(Specifically, non-tracked files that were copied into the checkout dir by a Run Script phase persist between integrations.)

Is there any way to force a bot to always nuke its checkout directory and do a clean checkout from source control every time?

Is it even possible to force Xcode (Server?) to show me *where* the checkout directory is? (I know it's hidden in the bowels of `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/` somewhere, but I can't see into those directories as a normal user because of their permissions. I'm thinking of a "Show in Finder" menu option or the like.)

Comment: For my future reference, the built products (`.xcarchive` et al) are in `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Trigger to the Bot in the bot settings to achieve this.

In your local XCode select your bot, right click "Edit Bot...", triggers, and then + Add Trigger in the "Before Integration" section.

Comment: And what should the trigger do? `rm -rf $XCS_SOURCE_DIR`? That strikes me as a bit brave. Have you tried it?

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't really do what I want. It did seem to nuke the checkouts dir when I first ran it, but then that integration failed immediately afterward. Subsequently removing the trigger and integrating again appears to be re-attempting the build with a fresh checkout.